# BreezeJS intercept server response

Tags: asp.net, breeze

Due to an issue with ASP.NET Identity 2.0, the server returns HTTP 200 with a message saying HTTP 400 and I am trying to intercept it in order to redirect the user to the login page. This is the code I have but it seems that the site does not progress any longer. I understand that the issue is resolved in ASP.NET Identity 3.0 but it is not an option right now. Any ideas on the code below?

```
var ajaxAdapter = breeze.config.getAdapterInstance('ajax');

ajaxAdapter.requestInterceptor = function (requestInfo) {
requestInfo.success = function (response) {
    // process response message here.
    return response;
}};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing this by assigning the original success function to a variable and then calling it after my own code:

```
var ajaxAdapter = breeze.config.getAdapterInstance('ajax');

ajaxAdapter.requestInterceptor = function (requestInfo) {
var oldSuccessFn = requestInfo.success;

requestInfo.success = function (data, statusText, jqXHR) {
    if (data.Message == "Authorization has been denied for this request.") {
        signOut();
    } else {
        var result;
        oldSuccessFn.call(result, data, statusText, jqXHR);
        return result;
    }
},
```